# Segmentation fault when getting public class member through pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, c++14

I have a few classes that handle setting a player's chosen region in a game.

The Region class:

```
class Region 
{
public:
    string name;

    Region(string n) : name(n) {}
}
```

The player controller class:

```
class PlayerController
{
public 
    Region* playerRegion
}
```

The RegionHandler class:

```
class RegionHandler 
{
public:

    enum RegionCode { EU, RU, SEA, AM, CH, AF};

    PlayerController playerController;

    vector<Region> regions;

    RegionHandler() {
        static const char *names[] = { "russia", "sea", "america", "china", "africa"};
        for (auto n : names)
            regions.emplace_back(n);
    }


    void chooseRegion() {

        int playerRegionIndex;

        cout << "Regions:\n"
             << "0. Europe\n"
             << "1. Russia\n"
             << "2. SEA\n"
             << "3. America\n"
             << "4. China\n"
             << "5. Africa\n";

        do {
            cout << "Select a region\n> ";
            cin >> playerRegionIndex; // Get user to input a region int
        }

        while(playerRegionIndex < 0 || playerRegionIndex > 5);

        playerController.playerRegion = &regions[playerRegionIndex];
    }
}
```

Main:

```
int main() 
{
    RegionHandler regionHandler;
    PlayerController playerController;

    regionHandler.chooseRegion();

    string mystr = playerController.playerRegion->name;

}
```

But when I try to get the name of the region the player has chosen into a string or in cout which I should be able to do, I get a segmentation fault even though name is a public string which should be set in RegionHandler. I get no other errors and the program works fine otherwise.

The segmentation fault occurs after I enter a number for playerRegionIndex and is caused by `string mystr = playerController.playerRegion->name;`

I have never come across a segmentation fault before and I don't really understand the GDB output, which is why I am asking this.

Full source on [GitHub](https://github.com/exitc0d3/Contingency-Project/blob/master/main.cpp)

Compiled on the new Ubuntu Bash for Windows using `g++ main.cpp -std=c++1y -o main -g`

GDB Output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007f6f237ab45b in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `regionHandler.chooseRegion()` sets up `regionHandler.playerController`. The local variable in `main`, also named `playerController`, is unaffected, its `playerRegion` member remains uninitialized, containing garbage. Also note that you have 6 `RegionCode`s but only 5 elements in `regions` vector.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not sure you have read my question. I have provided the full source of the program which is compilable and all of the relevant lines of code that could be combined into a main.cpp and compiled to work fine. I have given the gdb output and explained that I do not understand it very well. I have been as concise as possible in my code and I haven't just dumped it asking for people to debug it for me. I do not understand what is causing the problem and that is why I have asked the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [segmentation fault accessing a private class variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351233/segmentation-fault-accessing-a-private-class-variable)

Comment: @PaulRoub the only similarity I can see between the two questions is the fact that both yield a segmentation fault. The issue here is caused by a bad dependency relationship between two classes as both JJTO and Igor have pointed out. None of the answers on the question you have linked as a possible duplicate do anything to help answer this question.

Comment: In both cases, uninitialized member variables are being referenced (take a look - when, in the code shown, is `main()`'s  `playerController.playerRegion` initialized to *anything*?. In both cases this is rooted in confusion between member variables, and local-to-the-caller variables, with the same name. It may not be a perfect duplicate, but if you don't see the similarities, take another look.

Answer (score 1):

Like Igor said, local variable in main `playerController` is not being affected by local variable `regionHandler`. I'm still learning OOP so correct me if I'm wrong but playerController's region is set by regionHandler.chooseRegion() method. This is a dependency relationship between the two classes.

```
class PlayerController
{

private:

public 
    Region* playerRegion;
    PlayerController()
    {...
      RegionHandler handle;
      string region = handle.getRegion(); //using RegionHandler class's method
      playerRegion = new Region(region); 
      ...
    }

}

class RegionHandler 
{
public:

    enum RegionCode { EU, RU, SEA, AM, CH, AF};

    PlayerController playerController;

    vector<Region> regions;

    RegionHandler() {
        static const char *names[] = { "russia", "sea", "america", "china", "africa"};
        for (auto n : names)
            regions.emplace_back(n);
    }


    string chooseRegion() { //change the return type to string

        int playerRegionIndex;

        cout << "Regions:\n"
             << "0. Europe\n"
             << "1. Russia\n"
             << "2. SEA\n"
             << "3. America\n"
             << "4. China\n"
             << "5. Africa\n";

        do {
            cout << "Select a region\n> ";
            cin >> playerRegionIndex; // Get user to input a region int
        }

        while(playerRegionIndex < 0 || playerRegionIndex > 5);

       return &regions[playerRegionIndex];
    }
}
```